# tensorflow keras sequence models - how to only predict output of last step

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am developing a sequence model by using `tf.keras` library.

Assume that I have 5 time steps and each time step essentially has an output.
Number of features in each time step is - say - 4. And I am working on a classification problem and the output can be one of 0, 1, or 2.

For example, following is a train example.

```
Step 1 input: `[0, 5, 4, 5]` and output = `0`
Step 2 input: `[1, 2, 2, 7]` and output = `1`
Step 3 input: `[7, 5, 3, 4]` and output = `0`
Step 4 input: `[4, 5, 1, 2]` and output = `1`
Step 5 input: `[8, 5, 4, 5]` and output = `2`
```

When training my model, I want to train it in a way so that...
In step 1, if your input is `[0, 5, 4, 5]`, then output for this timestep is `0`.
In step 2, if your input is `[1, 2, 2, 7]`, then output for this timestep is `1`.
And so on....

But later on in the production, I will only expect my model to estimate the output from the last timestep. For instance:

```
Step 1 input: `[0, 5, 4, 5]` and output = `0`
Step 2 input: `[1, 2, 2, 7]` and output = `1`
Step 3 input: `[7, 5, 3, 4]` and output = `0`
Step 4 input: `[4, 5, 1, 2]` and output = `1`
Step 5 input: `[8, 5, 4, 5]` and output = **`?`**
```

Based on this, when training my model, I am a bit confused about how I should build and be training my model? Since I am only interested in the output of last step but still would like to help my model during the training phase by providing the outputs of previous steps prior to the final step, I wonder how I should construct the model? If I provide ouputs of all timesteps as expected input, as far as I understand it, loss/cost is calculated based on that. For instance, if the output of 3rd timestep is calculated wrong, the cost will be increasing. It is maybe expected, but the important thing for me is the output of last step and I am primarily interested in making a correct prediction in the last time step.
How do I construct my model by using `tf.keras` for such a case?

( Or, if I still need to train my model in a way so that it tries to estimate the output of each time step separately.. At the end, I would still like to calculate the accuracy based on only the output of last step. )

Any help will highly be appreciated!

Comment: I think you should not expect a definite answer other than "Experiment and see what's the best!" in this case. Training by considering the labels of all the timesteps, rather than only the last timestep, may or may not yield good results based on the specific task and dataset you are working on as well the architecture of the model. Try both approaches and see what works the best.

Comment: @today, thank you for your comment. I actually agree. But the major thing I am confused about how I build my model if I want to use labels from previous time steps as well. Adding the label to the feature list is a solution but I cannot provide the label of the last time step (bcz it is what I want to predict). In such a case, I wonder how the (LSTM) model should be built?

Comment: You can build the model based on only the label of last timestep (i.e. throw away all the other labels). Alternatively, you can build a model such that it predicts the labels of all the timesteps (probably you may need to set `return_sequences=True` on the LSTM layers). So there is no need to use the labels as features.